# Как будет правильнее: возвращать структуру из функции или же передавать на нее указатель?

Tags: c++, функции, оптимизация, структуры

Собственно вопрос в заглавии, не давно перешел на С++ и сейчас пока просто возвращаю из функций структуру как обычный параметр, однако в сети советуют передавать в функцию указатель на структуру и внутри заполнять ее. Как правильнее будет ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код, того, что сделали - добавьте в ваш вопрос. не нужно писать его в комментарий или отвечать на собственный вопрос.

Comment: @And 

Что то вроде: http://cpp.sh/4fua7

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вопрос на самом деле про C. Это там нормальной практикой является передавать в функцию указатель и заполнять ее. Для С++ же ответ будет сильно зависить от версии языка.

Comment: в сети это где-то конкретно? А правильнее заполнять структуру в конструкторе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее вопрос вкуса :)

Ранее рекомендовалось при больших структурах возврат осуществлять через переданный указатель (или ссылку) - чтобы избежать излишнего копирования. В настоящее время грамотно написанные перемещающие присваивание и копирование (или просто нормальный современный оптимизатор) и так обеспечивают отсутствие копирования - сразу заполняя структуру, которой результат будет присвоен.

Так что рассматривать нужно уже и прочие факторы. Одним из которых, и немаловажным, является *понятность* кода. Это *мое личное мнение*, но возврат структуры, а не передача ее, в общем случае выглядит более понятно и удобочитаемо.

Если на первое, второе и прочие места выходит эффективность - то следует выполнять проверки, эксперименты и изменения, и только по их результатам принимать взвешенное и обоснованное решение.